# Java generics - getting a method to return the same type as the first parameter

Tags: java, generics, types, return, return-type

Something like this is what Im trying to achieve:

```
public Attribute<?> getAttribute(Class<? extends Attribute> attributeClass){
  for(Attribute attribute: attributes)
    if(attributeClass.isInstance(attribute)) return attributeClass.cast(attribute);
  return null;
}
```

where the Attribute< ?> is obviously the incorrect part.

I want the return type of this method to be of attributeClass, but I cant seem to figure out how to get that. I should note that I am aware that I could just use Attribute as a return type, but this method would be mostly called in this fashion:

```
AttributeType1 attributeType1 = getAttribute(AttributeType1.class);
```

...and I am trying to avoid having to cast every time.

Help appreciated.

Comment: It would help a bit to filter out the right answer if we would know how `Attribute` looks like. Is it `interface Attribute<T extends Attribute<T>>`, or something like this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

this is what you need

```
public <T extends Attribute> T getAttribute(Class<T> attributeClass){
```

you need to specify the generic type before the return type

Answer (score 5):

```
public <T extends Attribute> T getAttribute(Class<T> attributeClass) {
```

should work